# regex matching tutorial

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, non-greedy

I've been using regex for years, I've read several tutorials and references (emacs regex reference is my bible), but I still have problems understanding matching. Is there a good comprehensive tutorial on regex matching with abundant examples? Can anybody give me a link where I can finally deeply understand regex matching?

Example ot the problem bothering me.

```
haystack = "[{one, {one, andahalf}},\n {{two, zero}, two},\n {{threezero}, three},\n {four}]"
pattern = "({.+})"
```

Result is:

```
{one, {one, andahalf}}
{{two, zero}, two}
{{threezero}, three}
{four}
```

Now, what is that exactly? Greedy or nongreedy (it's C# Regexp.Matches)?

Why, o why the (nongreedy) result isn't:

```
{one, {one, andahalf}
{{two, zero}
{{threezero}
{four}
```

(matching first possible pair of {})

Or (greedy):

```
{one, {one, andahalf}},\n {{two, zero}, two},\n {{threezero}, three},\n {four}
```

(maching greatest possible pair of {})

Of course, the actual result is exactly what I need, and I'm very happy that regex reads my mind, but I'd rather that I read his mind :-D So, does anybody have any decent tutorial on regex matching which will help me understand how this match did what it did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happened to work is that those patterns are separated by newlines, and by default the dot (in the `.+` part of your regex) matches anything but a newline. To change that behaviour, compile the regex with `RegexOptions.Singleline` set.

So it's just a coincidence that the braces were correctly balanced during this greedy match.

A good regex tutorial can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info.

By the way, for safety, braces should always be escaped (`\{`, `\}`). The .NET regex engine happens to recognize that they can't mean a quantifier in this context, but other engines will fail to compile this regex.

Comment: Ah, newlines. Right. Thanks! Silly me. And, thanks for the escaping tip.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy one... Read: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)

This is hands down, the most useful book I've read in my life. Very clear, accurate and error-free presentation of the material. An entertaining and thorough tutorial to gain a deep understanding of exactly how an NFA regex engine works under the hood and how you can utilize this knowledge to begin *crafting* accurate and efficient regexes (for just about any any language).

When it comes to regex, there are two types of people: those who have read this book, and those who haven't.

(You can spot the ones who haven't by all the `.*` dot-stars in their expressions.)

Comment: Thanks, that book is awesome! I'm pretty sure I'm buying it, thanks.